# How to integrate google search results in a spring mvc app

Tags: google, spring, integration, spring-mvc

Here's what am trying to do (and searching for similar hasn't shown any results anywhere):

On my website - provide an input box which will search google for results. I want to display those results on my page and customize the URL of those search results. So whenever a user clicks on the displayed result, my application will (internally search for profile pages and) provide the future course of action. The only integration of google is, providing the search results (and probably the map coordindates)
Env: Spring mvc, jsp, hibernate.

Can some one please advise on how can I achieve this ? 
I dont where to begin but I have read about the Google custom search, but I think that is only for searching within your site or to redirect users to relevant sites found from the result.

Comment: You can use this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054377/java-implementation-of-google-custom-search-api